# Import Mutiple records using multiple import buttons in datagrid in WPF using BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, backgroundworker

**Requirement :** 
To allow user to import multiple records and to allow to click on multiple import buttons (In DATAGRID).

I am able to process import button functionality when user clicks on single import button, however if user clicks on another import button, I didn't able to import.

Below is my code for the same.

```
 BackgroundWorker bgWorkerUpdate = new BackgroundWorker();

 // Constructor
 public ImportedKeywords()
 {
      bgWorkerUpdate.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgWorkerUpdateDoWork);
      bgWorkerUpdate.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgWorkerUpdate_Completed);
 }

 private void Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
       if (!bgWorkerUpdate.IsBusy) bgWorkerUpdate.RunWorkerAsync(objSearchRequest);
       else
       {
           bgWorkerUpdate = new BackgroundWorker();
           bgWorkerUpdate.RunWorkerAsync(objSearchRequest);
       }
 }


     public void bgWorkerUpdateDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            SearchRequest objSearchRequest = (SearchRequest)e.Argument;//txtUserName.Text;
            importCount = new AdvancedSearching().SearchContent(objSearchRequest, totalRecords, totalRecordsImported, recordsToImport, keywordID, selectedPriority);
        }


  void bgWorkerUpdate_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            imgLoading.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            if (importCount == 0)
            {
                lblMessage.Content = "No record found to import.";
                lblMessage.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            }
            else
            {

                lblMessage.Content = importCount + " Record(s) imported successfully.";
                lblMessage.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
                BindList(Convert.ToInt32(tbStartPage.Text), txtSearch.Text, "test");
                MaintainSortingWithPaging(Convert.ToInt32(tbStartPage.Text));
            }
            HideLoading();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new instance of a `BackgroundWorker`, you have to subscribe to the `DoWork` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events again. Otherwise, it's not doing anything when you run it.

```
if (!bgWorkerUpdate.IsBusy)
    bgWorkerUpdate.RunWorkerAsync(objSearchRequest);
else
{
    bgWorkerUpdate = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorkerUpdate.DoWork += bgWorkerUpdateDoWork;
    bgWorkerUpdate.RunWorkerCompleted+= bgWorkerUpdate_Completed;
    bgWorkerUpdate.RunWorkerAsync(objSearchRequest);
}
```

But if all you want to do is run each job in a new thread if the old one is still running, perhaps you could research other constructs, such as [`Task.Run`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html).

Comment: if I am running multiple background, then how it will work. will these all imports work parallel ?
If not then which is the exact way to go ?

Comment: ok thanks, i will go with BackgroundWorker for now :) and will get back to you in case of any asistance :)